# Getting Problem TargetVersion from 1.6 to 1.5 in Android?

Tags: android

I have developed an application with Target build as API 4. It supports Normal Screen and all Densities. But Now i would need to set the App's Target as API 3. In Eclipse Environment, I changed the Build Target to API 3. But  I get the Following Error.

- R file gone Automatically. So i get Can not Resolved error allover my app where R is present.
- `drawable-ldpi`,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-hdpi`, `value-long`,etc are not supported.

How to Downgrade my app to Android 1.5  and It should can accessible on up to Android 2.1? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget about -v4 and other things http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

And a "Project->Clean…" should be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

1. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi are only supported in Android 1.6+, so you have to move images to a single `drawable` folder.
2. set `minSdkVersion` to **3**, and `targetSdkVersion` to **7**
3. Project -> Clean to generate new `R` resources